# Does an abstract `def __init__` make sense?

Tags: python, initializer, abstract-methods

I want implementations of my abstract class to accept an integer. For this, I can

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, i: int):
        pass
```

and then implementations will be like

```
class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, i: int):
        ...
```

but since I can change the signature of `__init__` without violating LSP, I can also

```
class Sub2(Sub):
    def __init__(self, s: str):
        ...
```

and the signature of `Base.__init__` is lost, and isn't enforced by the `ABC`. That is, only direct descendants of `Base` must have the same `__init__` signature. If subclasses were strictly required to call superclass's `__init__` methods, this wouldn't be a problem, because `Sub2` would need to provide an `int` to `Sub`, but afaict that's optional.

Given this, does making `__init__` abstract make sense? Or, more broadly, should subclasses ever be expected to have a given type signature?

Comment: Of course type hints are used by type checkers, but it is also a documentation for human. If you recommend subclasses type signature for `__init__`, putting it into abstract `__init__` will have good meaning of recommendation.

Comment: Given the nature of abstract methods, making `__init__` abstract seems like it would just be a very strong hint that the child do something specific in its `__init__` method, rather than simply assuming that the upstream `__init__` is sufficient. Being abstract doesn't say anything about the required signature, only that something by that *name* is defined.