# Python type hinting for generic container constructor

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

What is the correct typing to use for the below marked in ???, where we cast a generic iterable data container type to an iterable container of different type?

```
def foo(itr:Iterable, cast_type:???) -> ???:  (For Py 3)
    # type: (Iterable[Any], ???) -> ???    (For Py 2.7)
    return cast_type(itr)

foo([1,2], cast_type=set) # Example 1
foo(set([1,2]), cast_type=list) # Example 2 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No parameterized type variables!

The problem is that so far the Python typing system does not allow [higher-kinded variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548), meaning type variables that are parameterized with yet another type variable. This would be helpful here, since we could define a type variable `T` annotate `itr` with `Iterable[T]`, then define for example `It` as a type variable bounded by `Iterable[T]` and annotate `cast_type` as `type[It[T]]`, and finally annotate the return type as `It[T]`.

Alas, this is not possible yet (but in the making it seems), so we need to work around that.

### No safe `__init__` signature

The next problem is that there is no common constructor interface in the [collections ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) allowing an argument to be passed. We might be tempted to do the following:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any, TypeVar

It = TypeVar("It", bound=Iterable[Any])

def foo(itr: Iterable[Any], cast_type: type[It]) -> It:
    return cast_type(itr)
```

But the problem is that `mypy` will correctly give us the error `Too many arguments for "Iterable"  [call-arg]` for that last line. This problem remains the same, no matter which one of the abstract base classes we pick (like `Collection` or `Set` or what have you).

### Extend the protocol

(**EDIT**: See the last section for why the `__init__` protocol solution may cause problems and why it may be better to use `Callable` instead of `type`.)

To avoid this issue, we can introduce our own [custom protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) that inherits from `Iterable` and also introduces a common `__init__` interface:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar


class ConstructIterable(Iterable[Any], Protocol):
    def __init__(self, arg: Iterable[Any]) -> None: ...


It = TypeVar("It", bound=ConstructIterable)


def foo(itr: Iterable[Any], cast_type: type[It]) -> It:
    return cast_type(itr)


a = foo([1, 2], cast_type=set)
b = foo({1, 2}, cast_type=list)
reveal_type(a)
reveal_type(b)
```

Those last two lines are for `mypy` and if we run that in `--strict` mode over this script, we get no errors and the following info:

```
note: Revealed type is "builtins.set[Any]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Any]"
```

So far so good, the container types are inferred correctly from our argument types.

### Preserve the element types selectively

But we are losing the element type information this way. It is currently just `Any`. As I said, there is no good way to solve this right now, but we can work around that, if we want to decide on the most common use cases for that function.

If we anticipate it being called most often with common container types like `list`, `tuple` and `set` for example, we can write [overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) specifically for those and leave a catch-all non-generic `Iterable` case as a fallback. That last case will then still drop the element type information, but at least the other signatures will preserve it.

Here is an example:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar, overload


class ConstructIterable(Iterable[Any], Protocol):
    def __init__(self, _arg: Iterable[Any]) -> None: ...


T = TypeVar("T")
It = TypeVar("It", bound=ConstructIterable)


@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[list[Any]]) -> list[T]:
    ...

@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[tuple[Any, ...]]) -> tuple[T, ...]:
    ...

@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[set[Any]]) -> set[T]:
    ...

@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[It]) -> It:
    ...

def foo(
    itr: Iterable[Any],
    cast_type: type[ConstructIterable],
) -> ConstructIterable:
    return cast_type(itr)
```

Test it again with `mypy`:

```py
...

a = foo([1, 2], cast_type=set)
b = foo({1., 2.}, cast_type=list)
c = foo([1, 2], cast_type=tuple)
d = foo({1., 2.}, cast_type=frozenset)
reveal_type(a)
reveal_type(b)
reveal_type(c)
reveal_type(d)
```

Output:

```
note: Revealed type is "builtins.set[builtins.int]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.float]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.frozenset[Any]"
```

As you can see, at least the first three cases correctly preserved the element types. I am afraid this not-so-elegant solution is as good as it gets with the current type system limitations.

---

### PS

It seemed as though your question included one about Python 2, but I don't think that merits a response. Nobody should be using Python 2 today. Not to mention the typing system was essentially non-existent back then. The solution I showed above requires `3.9`, but can probably be made compatible with slightly older versions of Python by using `typing_extensions`, as well as the deprecated `typing.List`, `typing.Tuple`, and such.

---

### EDIT

Thanks to @joel for pointing out that `__init__` signatures are not checked, when passing subclasses. Instead of using `type`, it might be safer to go with the supertype `Callable`, then specify the argument and return type accordingly. This also makes the custom protocol unnecessary.

The adjusted workaround solution would then look like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload


T = TypeVar("T")
It = TypeVar("It", bound=Iterable[Any])


@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[list[Any]]) -> list[T]:
    ...


@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[tuple[Any, ...]]) -> tuple[T, ...]:
    ...


@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: type[set[Any]]) -> set[T]:
    ...


@overload
def foo(itr: Iterable[T], cast_type: Callable[[Iterable[Any]], It]) -> It:
    ...


def foo(
    itr: Iterable[Any],
    cast_type: Callable[[Iterable[Any]], It],
) -> It:
    return cast_type(itr)
```

The `mypy` output for out test lines is essentially the same, but for the last call revealing `"builtins.frozenset[_T_co`1]"` instead, which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: note [abstract `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56040196/5986907) and [calling `type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73450054/5986907) have significant pitfalls

Comment: @joel Could you be more specific about what exactly you think is problematic about the way I used those here? Because there are no issues regarding type safety as evidenced by the `mypy` checks, so I am curious what problems you see emerging here. And the posts you linked have little to do with the matter at hand.

Comment: the types in "Extend the Protocol" [allow `foo([], Foo)`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11) where `class Foo: def __init__(self): pass` (plus an `__iter__` method). From what I can tell, the signature of `__init__` is disregarded by both `type` and for abstract `__init__`s

Comment: @joel Thank you for pointing that out. I did not realize the type checking ignores clearly unsafe overrides of `__init__`. Just because that is done frequently does not mean it is safe, but I guess that was yet another trade-off in favor of "less hassle" against the Liskov substitution principle. But that is another discussion entirely. I added a solution using `Callable` as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced this is possible in python. The types would be something like

```
T = TypeVar("T")

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Iterable)
G = TypeVar("G")

def foo(itr: F[T], cast_type: Callable[[F[T]], G[T]]) -> G[T]:
    return cast_type(itr)
```

but typevars `F` and `G` are parametrized by other types, which Python [doesn't support](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548).